# Ошибка при передаче файла через AJAX

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Локалхост, передаю файл через AJAX-запрос. Массивы создаются и передаются в php файл, но про попытке разобрать всё на переменные получаю ошибку cервера 500. Как я понимаю, дело совсем не в сервере, а что-то не так в том файле-получателе. Пока пердавал только строковые было всё в порядке. Проверил валидатором синтаксис, ошибок нет.
Вот файл-получатель **add_project.php**:

```html
<?php

 $title = $_POST['title'];
 $description = $_POST['description'];
 $file = $_FILES['fileToUpload'];

 $fileName = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
 $fileTmpName = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
 $fileSize = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'];
 $fileError = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'];
 $fileType = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'];

 $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
 $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

 $allowed = $array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg');

 $error = '';
 if(strlen($title) <= 3)
  $error = 'Введите название'; 
 else if (strlen($description) <= 5)
  $error = 'Введите описание';
 else if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
  if ($fileError === 0){
   if ($fileSize < 5000){
    $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
    $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
    move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
    }  else {
     $error = 'Файл не должен превышать 5Мб';
     }
  } else {
   $error = 'Принимаются изображения только в  форматах png, jpg, jpeg';
   }
 } else {
  $error = 'Принимаются изображения только в форматах png, jpg, jpeg';
  }

 if($error != ''){
  echo $error;
  exit();
 }

 require_once '../mysql_connect.php';

 $sql = 'INSERT INTO project(title, description, text, date, author) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)';
 $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $query->execute([$title, $description, $fileDestination, time(), $_COOKIE['log']]);

 echo 'Готово';
?>
```

**Форма и AJAX запрос:**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="title">Название</label>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control"><br>
      <label for="description">Описание</label>
      <textarea name="description" id="description" class="form-control"></textarea><br>

      <label for="file" class="mt-5">Добавьте изображения</label>
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br>

      <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2" id="errorBlock"></div><br>

      <button type="submit" id="send_prjct" class="btn btn-dark mt-3">Добавить</button>
</form>

<script>
  $("#data").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();    
            var formData = new FormData(this);

   
   $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/add_project.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
     dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
     if (data == 'Готово'){
      $('#send_prjct').text('Выполнено');
      $('#errorBlock').hide();
     } else {
      $('#errorBlock').show();
      $('#errorBlock').text(data);
     }
    }  
   });
  });  
 </script>
```

Comment: есть возможность посмотреть логи веб-сервера ? (обычно при таких ошибках там показывает что и где упало)

Comment: Это локальный сервер. Подскажи, как это сделать?

Comment: какой вебсервер стоит apache или nginx ? какая ос линукс или винда ?

Comment: эм, а разве форма отправляется в json?

Comment: Действительно нет, это осталось от попыток сделать что-либо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочий вариант:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="title">Название</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control"><br>
    <label for="description">Описание</label>
    <textarea name="description" id="description" class="form-control"></textarea><br>

    <label for="file" class="mt-5">Добавьте изображения</label>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br>

    <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2" id="errorBlock"></div><br>

    <button type="submit" id="send_prjct" class="btn btn-dark mt-3">Добавить</button>
</form>

<script>
        $("#data").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();    
            var formData = new FormData(this);    

            $.ajax({
                url: 'add_project.php', // Путь для теста изменен
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                 //dataType: 'json',//******** это лишнее
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data == 'Готово'){
                        $('#send_prjct').text('Выполнено');
                        $('#errorBlock').hide();
                    } else {
                        $('#errorBlock').show();
                        $('#errorBlock').text(data);
                    }
                }       
            });
        });     
    </script>
```

Файл `add_project.php` (путь изменен для теста)

```
<?php
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $file = $_FILES['fileToUpload']; // а что здесь? - это массив

    $fileName = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg');// тут знак переменной убран

    $error = '';
    if(strlen($title) <= 3)
        $error = 'Введите название'; 
    else if (strlen($description) <= 5)
        $error = 'Введите описание';
    else if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
        if ($fileError === 0){
            if ($fileSize < 5000){
                $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
                $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
             }  else {
                $error = 'Файл не должен превышать 5Мб';
                }
        } else  {
            $error = 'Принимаются изображения только в  форматах png, jpg, jpeg';
            }
    } else {
        $error = 'Принимаются изображения только в форматах png, jpg, jpeg';
        }

    if($error != ''){
        echo $error;
        exit();
    }

    // Это для теста отключено
    /*require_once '../mysql_connect.php';

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO project(title, description, text, date, author) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)';
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute([$title, $description, $fileDestination, time(), $_COOKIE['log']]);*/

    echo 'Готово';
?>
```